# Replacing file for specific program

Tags: windows, vfs

The list of things I have:

- Windows 8.
- A program ("foo") that executes another program ("bar").
- A "bar".
- A replacement ("baz") for "bar".

Now the "foo" executes the "bar", but I need it to execute the "baz", which will execute "bar" and do things with stdout. I guess I need to create a VFS, but I dunno how. This VFS should not work on child processes. What should I do?

No, I can't replace "bar" with "baz" system-wide because the "bar" is WMI client.

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using.

Comment: @AntonioBardazzi there's no any code, I do not have sources of "foo" and "bar". The "baz" isn't written right now.